# integrating with existing html page django-page-cms

Tags: python, django

I have installed django-page-cms successfully i think. Like other cms, it is also for creating new pages. But I already have html pages in my project. How to integrate with that?

They want me to put place holder in html page, like:

> {% load pages_tags %}

but I think this will bring the content from the already created page in admin

Can anyone tell me how to integrate with my existing pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create page in admin console. Then add the placeholder in your template
like what tutorial saying

> {% get_page "news" as news_page %}
>
>   {% for new in news_page.get_children %}
>   `<li>`
>   {{ new.publication_date }}
>   {% show_content new body %}
>   {% endfor %}